# How to iterate over class variables from Handlebars in ember-cli?

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, ember-cli

I'd like to iterate over a class variable array in Handlebars in ember-cli to generate a list of checkboxes (categories), with the appropriate ones checked off based on which categories the model belongs to.

I have several issues:
- I can't figure out how to access the class variable in ember-cli. I've seen tutorials showing that in ember.js, it's just App.Listing.CATEGORIES, but I'm not getting any passes through my each loop.
- How to check off the appropriate box? I have some janky code below that probably doesn't work.

listing.js:

```
import DS from "ember-data";

var Listing = DS.Model.extend({
    categories: DS.attr(), // string array
});

Listing.reopenClass({
    CATEGORIES: ['park', 'outdoors']
});

export default Listing;
```

show.hbs:

```
<ul>
{{#each category in CATEGORIES}}
<li>{{input type="checkbox" name=category checked=categories.contains(category)}} {{category}}</li>

{{/each}}
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Handlebars templates can’t look up classes like that, nor does complex logic like `categories.contains(category)` work. You’ll need to add a computed property to the controller or component to supply proxy objects to the template. Assuming it’s a controller, here’s a rough example:

```
export default Ember.Controller.extend({
  selectableCategories: function() {
    var model = this.get('model');

    return model.constructor.CATEGORIES.map(function(category) {
      var categoryProxy = Ember.Object.create({
        model: model,
        name: category,
        checked: function(key, value) {
          var model = this.get('model');

          // setter; the checkbox value has changed
          if (arguments.length > 1) {
            if (model.get('categories').contains(this.get('name'))) {
              model.get('categories').removeObject(this.get('name'));
            }
            else {
              model.get('categories').addObject(this.get('name'));
            }
          }

          // getter; the template is checking whether the checkbox should be checked
          return model.get('categories').contains(this.get('name'));
        }.property('model.categories')
      });

      return categoryProxy;
    });
  }.property('model.categories')
});
```

The `selectableCategories` computed property returns an array of objects that observe the model’s `categories` attribute and represent whether or not each category is found within it.

Then in your template, you can use the proxy objects like this:

```
{{#each category in selectableCategories}}
  {{input type="checkbox" name=category.name checked=category.checked}} {{category.name}}
{{/each}}
```

Comment: I dropped your code above into controllers/listings/show.js. Chrome debugger tells me that model.constructor.CATEGORIES is undefined. Why model.constructor.CATEGORIES instead of model.CATEGORIES? At any rate, neither one worked. When I replace with a hard-coded array, the error goes away (no surprise), and I get the right number of check boxes, but no category names. The Ember debugger tells me there are three objects in selectableCategories, but they don't have any properties. I followed what you were doing, so not sure why it's not working.

Comment: hmm, sorry it didn’t work. I think you need `model.constructor.CATEGORIES` because it’s stored on the class, not in each instance. You can verify with the inspector if that’s true. Maybe set up a JSBin and I can look at it further? I wrote the answer without it being tied to any live code, so I could have missed something.

Comment: You could just set a computed property on the controller that returns `model.constructor.CATEGORIES` to verify that functionality. Also, there’s [this library](https://github.com/rsschermer/ember-multiselect-checkboxes) for this purpose.

Comment: I found a missing comma in my model dictionary definition. Fixing that made the model.constructor.CATEGORIES reference work. I managed to replicate my remaining issue (no category names showing up) in JSBin: http://jsbin.com/hidaqovigo/3/edit

The plugin you noted looks great. I'm interested in learning Ember, so I may use the plugin, but want to understand why the current code doesn't work.

Comment: ugh, I made a simple mistake in constructing the proxy object; should have used `Ember.Object.create` rather than `new Ember.Object`.

Comment: It’s definitely sensible to try to understand how to implement this without an addon. Does my implementation make sense to you? It would be more elegant to implement this with components, but this solution was easier to represent here.

Comment: Yes! Solved! Thanks so much for following up with this. I'm not enough of a Javascript guy (yet) to have spotted new vs create.